# C# code keeps hitting a process 5656 exited with code -1 error, but not clear what the error is and where it's failing

Tags: asp.net, .net, youtube-api, azure-functions, c#-2.0

I am trying to take this sample Youtube API code https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert which upload's videos to Youtube channel, and I am wrapping this code inside an Azure function(Function1.cs). The problem I am seeing is that, if I run the function currently, it throws an error to the console, which I am not sure what the error means.

> C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.4.1\cli_x64\func.exe
>   (process 5656) exited with code -1.

I am literally just copying the sample code(just simplified few things) and putting it inside an Azure function. Am I missing any other logic in my function? I am suspecting that my function isn't reading the client_secrets.json or is it some other issue? One thing I did notice is that the function itself works fine, but the “processing and uploading video” is not working. Could please have look at my function and suggest what I am doing wrong? I would like
to verify, if my logic is right or if the implementation can be improved . Thank you.

Here is the sample Youtube API ‘upload’ code taken from (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/

And converting  that sample code into an Azure function:

Function1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace YoutubeUploadFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("video/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
            var VideoInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", myBlob, "video/*");
            await VideoInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Console Output:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2245 Commit hash: 1d094e2f3ef79b9a478a1621ea7ec3f93ac1910d)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.13139.0
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: 'a37bba12-9125-4af6-8c10-26daef57ef90'
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\UploadVideo\YoutubeUploadFunction\YoutubeUploadFunction\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\host.json'
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Host configuration file read:
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "version": "2.0"
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Reading functions metadata
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] 1 functions found
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Loading startup extension 'AzureStorage'
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Loaded extension 'AzureStorage' (3.0.4.0)
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Initializing Host. OperationId: 'a37bba12-9125-4af6-8c10-26daef57ef90'.
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=a37bba12-9125-4af6-8c10-26daef57ef90
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] LoggerFilterOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "MinLevel": "None",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "Rules": [
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "ProviderName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     },
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "LogLevel": "None",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "Filter": null
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     },
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]     }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   ]
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "IsEnabled": true
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] SingletonOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[3/16/2020 6:02:11 PM]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] QueuesOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "BatchSize": 16,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "NewBatchThreshold": 8,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00"
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] BlobsOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "CentralizedPoisonQueue": false
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] HttpOptions
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] {
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] }
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Starting JobHost
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Starting Host (HostId=desktopgq271u4-950774370, InstanceId=16bc66b5-e751-4c00-b383-6f705e303c13, Version=3.0.13139.0, ProcessId=5656, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Loading functions metadata
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] 1 functions loaded
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] Found the following functions:
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM] YoutubeUploadFunction.Function1.Run
[3/16/2020 6:02:12 PM]
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Initializing function HTTP routes
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] No HTTP routes mapped
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM]
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Host initialized (2033ms)
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Host started (2485ms)
[3/16/2020 6:02:14 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\UploadVideo\YoutubeUploadFunction\YoutubeUploadFunction\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[3/16/2020 6:02:19 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A74A8599'.

C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.4.1\cli_x64\func.exe (process 5656) exited with code -1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the code in a try catch to see if that gives you any details about the error?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question accordingly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sure I can try to simplify it.

Comment: That error just indicates that func.exe's main() function returned -1. No idea what that process does, but it probably wrote an error message to stdout.

Comment: @Jeremy what I expecting was, the function would open a browser and ask for my Youtube credentials for authentication. But instead it just returns an error.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe a browser isn't supported when executed in Azure Functions?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov do you have any inputs on this issue? From my testing, it seems that the function itself runs fine and gets triggered when there is a new blob uploaded. But what's not working is the Youtube Processing and Uploading.

Comment: No, except  based on comments in https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs your code is totally wrong to run server side.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry I didn't quite get what you meant by "totally wrong to run server side"?

Comment: The description of the class says "Do not use this class when executing on a web server, or any cases where the authenticating end-user is not able to do directly interact with a launched browser". You claim your code is in "Azure function" meaning where "end-user is not able to do directly interact with a launched browser" .

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so I guess what can you suggest I do? I mean my main reason to use Azure function is that I can add and call function to my Azure Logic app(to automate tasks). If there is a different approach please let me know.

Comment: @Peter no idea. I didn't work with either of these APIs. I just got lucky to know that you approach is not going to work (as it's basically first line of the info on class you use) but I can't suggest what would be right approach. Generally you'd send user credentials from client side (browser?) to service in some way as services can't authenticate as users.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some suggestions.

There are 3 different things: the Function platform, the Azure Storage Service and the Youtube API.

To narrow down your issue, you may try to:

1. Directly get video content from the local file system but Azure Storage Service. Then try to upload the video to see if it is possible to upload the video successfully.

   - If the video can be uploaded successfully, then the problem may be getting content from Storage in Function with the blob trigger.
   - If not, then you should check the Youtube API, I think.
2. Try to bind the input to [`CloudBlockBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp#usage) not a stream. Then manually get content from the `CloudBlockBlib` object.
3. Write a console application to check the whole workflow.

Comment: If you had a chance to verify my function1.cs code, do you think logically the code make sense?

Comment: Not a Youtuber. But based on my experience, I can successfully use Azure Storage Trigger in Azure Function.

Comment: Jack, I can say that the function works fine because, when I published it to azure portal and upload a video in my video container, the function gets triggered. The ISSUE is that it still doesn’t process the video and upload it to YouTube.